# Flutter getting data from API to build method

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I'm trying to accomplish what I though would be simple before I started learning flutter.

```
const apiKey = 'xxxxxx';
const coinApiURL = 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate';

class _CurrencyState extends State<CurrencyScreen> {

void getData() async {
http.Response response = await http.get('$coinApiURL/BTC/USD?apikey=$apiKey');

String data = response.body;
double exchangeRate = jsonDecode(data)['rate'];
print(exchangeRate);
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData(); // prints out the value
    print(exchangeRate); // error "Undefined name 'exchangeRate'"
    (...)
    child: Text($exchangeRate) // value has to be inserted here
  }
```

So while I can use the function getData to print the data that it contains, I can't print out the 'exchangeRate' value. Therefore I too can't insert the value into the Text widget.

Can anyone explain me in a simple words how is that working and how I can get the value of 'exchangeRate' variable and use it in the code?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: That doesn't really address my issue, but I updated my question  so it's easier to understand what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: you cannot do it that way, you have a `Future`  coming from `getData()` method so you have to use `FutureBuilder` as in the link i posted

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code so the `Text` widget is build after `getData` finish prosses http response data.

```
const apiKey = 'xxxxxx';
const coinApiURL = 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate';

class _CurrencyState extends State<CurrencyScreen> {

// fetch http data and return rate value 
Future<double> getData() async {
http.Response response = await http.get('$coinApiURL/BTC/USD?apikey=$apiKey');
String data = response.body;
double exchangeRate = jsonDecode(data)['rate'];
print(exchangeRate);
// return exchangeRate value
return exchangeRate;
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<double>(
    // assign getData() to futureBuilder
    future: getData(),
    builder: (BuildContext  context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
      // handle getData error
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error');
      }
      // handle success fetched data
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
      }
      // return progress indicator while loading data
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
     );
  }
```